# How to retrieve clientWidth of <content> container

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

Let's say we have template:

```js
var shadow = document.querySelector('#insider').createShadowRoot();
var template = document.querySelector('#templ');
shadow.appendChild(template.content);
template.remove();

console.debug(document.body.clientWidth)
console.debug(document.querySelector('#insider').clientWidth)
alert(document.body.clientWidth + " == " + document.querySelector('#insider').clientWidth + "?")
```

```html
<template id="templ">
    <content style="width: 50%"></content>
</template>

<div id="insider">
  test
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nogye8yc/

How can I get clientWidth of content area by most simplest obvious way in js?
Styles can be applied to a wrapper of `<content>` tag too, it doesn't change a lot.

Now it gives 100% width.

Thanks.

Comment: Because `#insider` has `width:auto` by default wich gives `100%` width.

Comment: clientWidth returns width in pixels and it equals of clientWidth of body. It should be halfed, I think.